# For how many distinct congruence classes $[a]$ modulo $631$ will there be integer solutions $x$ to the congruence $x^2= a \pmod{631}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

For how many distinct congruence classes $[a]$ modulo $631$ will there
be integer solutions $x$ to the congruence
$x^2 \equiv a \pmod{631}$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Write $x^2-a=(x-a)(x+a)=0$ in the field $\Bbb F_{631}$. What do you know about an equation $ab=0$ in a field?

Comment: We know that $(p-a)$ and $a$ are two solutions to the same quadratic congruence, $x^2\equiv b\pmod{p}$ where $b\equiv a^2$ and that congruence has exactly two solutions since $p$ is a prime. Therefore, every such pair in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ generates a distinct quadratic residue, which leaves us with only $(p-1)/2$ choices.

Answer (score 0):

Two hints: $631$ is prime, and recall Euclid's Lemma.